# Google time format for their API?

Tags: datetime, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm looking through the Google Calendar api docs. 
Looks like there's a time format I'm not familiar with:

`2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00`

What does the `T09` denote? Is this a time zone?

Answer (score 1):

Per their docs, its RFC3339. I should have read that. [link](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339)

Comment: And this is where you can find the information: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339#section-5.8

Answer (score 1):

```
2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00

As per your date format

2015 = yyyy;
05 = mm;
28 = dd;
T  = time separator;
09 = h;
00 = i;
00 = s;

-07:00 = These values are +/- based on the timezone (ex: +05:30 for Asia/Kolkata)
```

Answer (score 0):

The "2015-05-28" part is the date.

The T is a seperator.

The "09:00:00" part is the time.

The "-07:00" part is the time zone difference from GMT.

You can reproduce this with  `date('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO')`.